# Area within a given number of standard deviations from given mean

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, computational-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a variable with mean value of 18.85 and standard deviation of 1.45.

I want to define the area that is covered by 1.45 standard deviations left and 1.45 standard deviations on the right side of the mean using these statistics.

How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on the shape of the distribution.

Comment: @Henry assuming distribution is normal distribution

Comment: 22.27,
20.42,
19.69,
18.54,
21.84,
21.78,
19.38,
21.33,
18.49 say this is the data

Comment: What do you mean by 'define the area'? Is this for some class?

Comment: @Glen_b like 68% area is cover by one standard deviation

Comment: You want to find the area within 1.45 standard deviations of the mean for a normal random variable?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I want to find the area that is covered by 1.45 standard deviations on both (i.e., left and right) sides of the mean for a normal random variable.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal to work it out? Tables? software? Again, is this for some class?

Comment: @Glen_b No this is not for a class, just for my understanding. I have MS Excel and matlab at my disposal to play with the variable.

Comment: ... why not just multiply the standard deviation by 1.45 and subtract / add it to the mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: I suspect you're confused about something. Even though you said in comments you want 1.45 standard deviations either side of the mean, your standard deviation is itself 1.45, which makes me suspect you want *one* standard deviation either side of the mean: 18.85$\pm$1.45, which is the interval (17.4,20.3), which should contain 68% of the area (you quoted 68% yourself for 1 standard deviation either side of the mean).

You have to be very careful to be explicit about what you seek! In particular, don't muddle the number of standard deviations with the size of the standard deviation.

Nevertheless, I'll proceed on the assumption you want what you explicitly say in comments; the approach can be adapted to other areas easily, so once you're clear on what you want, you can adapt the approach yourself.

The following also assumes you're talking about population mean and standard deviation for your normal. If they're sample statistics the analysis involves t-distributions rather than normal distributions (but is somewhat similar).

---

Once you're to the point you're at - you know the cutoff z-value (1.45), and you want to find the area between -z and z,

[image]

then you can use some function that returns normal areas.

Any decent stats package (or even Excel) will give you functions to do this with.

For example, if you have a function that gives the cdf for a standard normal:

[image]

Then you could subtract 1/2 (for the area below 0),

[image]

and double that to get the original area. Since subtracting 1/2 and then doubling is the same as doubling and subtracting 1, we can do that.

[Matlab](http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) has `normcdf`, so

```
 2*normcdf(1.45)-1
```

would suffice (as would `normcdf(1.45)-normcdf(-1.45)`).

In [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/normsdist-HP005209194.aspx) the function `NORMSDIST` works:

```
2*NORMSDIST(1.45)-1
```

as does `NORM.S.DIST` (though it has slightly different arguments, check the help if you want to use it).

In R `2*pnorm(1.45)-1` does the same job, and so on....

--

If you don't have anything but a calculator handy, you can do quite well with [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson.27s_rule)* -- or one of the other numerical quadrature formulas. There are sophisticated approaches specifically designed for normal areas, but this generic approach is sufficient for most ordinary work, and if you've used it a few times it's easy to remember. It's barely any more complicated than the trapezoidal rule, and requires a lot less calculator punching for a given accuracy (the three-eighths rule can reduce work/improve accuracy still further).

* In accordance with Stigler's Law, it seems to have been used by Kepler long before Simpson came up with it.

So let's evaluate the area between 0 and 1.45 with 5 points (0.0000, 0.3625, 0.7250, 1.0875, 1.4500):

$\int_0^{1.45} \phi(x) dx \approx  \frac{0.3625}{3} [\phi(0)+4\,\phi(0.3625)+2\,\phi(0.725)+4\,\phi(1.0875)+\phi(1.45)]$

where $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal density, $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$.

$\hspace{2.3cm}=  \frac{0.3625}{3\sqrt{2\pi}} [e^{-0^2}+e^{-1.45^2/2}+4\,(e^{-0.3625^2/2}+e^{-1.0875^2/2})+2\,e^{-0.725^2/2}]$

$\hspace{2.3cm}\approx  0.048206\, [1+e^{-1.05125}+4\,(e^{-0.06570313}+e^{-0.5913281})+2\,e^{-0.2628125}]$

$\hspace{2.3cm}\approx  0.048206\, [1+0.3495+4\,(0.9364+0.5536)+2\,(0.7689)]$

$\hspace{2.3cm}\approx  0.4765$

... which in this case is accurate to the quoted number of figures. Of course, that's the right half of the required area (the green-shaded part of the third picture above), so you'd then double that for the area between -1.45 and 1.45.

If you already know some values (like the cdf at 1 and 2 or the area between -1 and 1 and the area between -2 and 2), you only need to use such a rule for the area to the nearest known value. This can dramatically improve accuracy or reduce the number of intervals needed.

Comment: this is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Could you please give a simple example with Simpson's rule. I mean, how to calculate similar value theoretically.

Comment: Well, it would be an approximation, and the more intervals the more accuracy, but sure.

Comment: Even example of an approximation would be handy!

Comment: Done... see the updated answer.

Comment: 68% was just an example to clarify my question.

Comment: @Gleb_b After calculating the area, then how to determine the corresponding boundary values of the variable.

Comment: After Calculating the area, then how to determine the actual values of the area boundaries of the variable?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking there. If you're asking how to compute the limits of the shaded region, you do that before, not after, calculating the area, since the area is a function of that value. If you're asking something else you're going to have to explain more clearly