# How to derive quantiles of a non-standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Let X = [11.17, 9.52, 10.69, 9.84, 10.84, 9.88, 10.28, 12.23, 8.49, 10.79] be a normally distributed data with mean = 10.37 and standard deviation = 1.02. How to determine the corresponding value to +1.02 and -1.02 standard deviations, which covers 69% area of the probability distribution.

Comment: The question is unclear as stated: do you ask what is the mean+standard deviation value? 10.37+1.02=11.39... A random variable does not take an actual value along the x-axis, but any value when realised. Please rephrase title and text.

Comment: @Xi'an No, I didn't asked for mean + standard deviation (i.e., 10.37 + 1.02 = 11.39). The min = 8.49 and the max = 12.23. How to determine the exact lower and upper values which covers 0.69% (derived from 1.02 from left and right side of the mean) area.

Comment: Please rephrase your title to How to derive quantiles of a non-standard distribution. The use of the same value 1.02 both for the empirical standard deviation and for the 84% quantile of the N(0,1) distribution is quite confusing.

Comment: The highly detailed and informative answer provided by [Glen_b](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125189/7224) to your earlier question already makes this point that you seem confused between the standard deviation of your sample and the normal quantiles.

Comment: what do you mean by 84% quantile?

Comment: $1.02$ is the $84.6\%$ quantile of the N(0,1) distribution, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X<1.02)=0.846$ and $\mathbb{P}(X<1.02)-\mathbb{P}(X<-1.02)=0.69$.

Comment: It may not be a good question but still I ask. Is there any way to link standard deviation of the empirical data with normal quantile. If yes, then how can we mathematically formulate it.

Comment: Why do you keep posting questions where the standard deviation and the number of standard deviations are the same? It's a very unsusual thing to do, so it suggests you have a misunderstanding. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This derivation follows from the linearity properties of the normal distribution.

Since for a standard normal $X\sim N(0,1)$, $-1.02\le X\le 1.02$ with probability $0.69$, for a normal $Y\sim N(10.37,1.02)$, $$9.33=-1.02\cdot1.02+10.37\le Y\sim1.02\cdot X+10.37\le 1.02\cdot 1.02+10.37=11.41$$

Comment: How did you get 9.33 on left hand side by 1.02*1.02 +10.37?

Comment: I corrected the typo, there was a - in front.